# Не импортируется withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Есть у меня такой компонент:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Car.css';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const Car = props => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div className={'Car'}>
      <h3>Сar name: {props.name}</h3>
      <p>Year: <strong>{props.year}</strong></p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Car);
```

Собственно проблема в withRouter: при запуске приложения через **yarn start**, оно перестает работать. Если же компонент высшего порядка убрать, то все работает должным образом. Какое-то время погуглив, я пришел к выводу, что в моей версии **react-router-dom** данный компонент называется по-другому, а откатываться до предыдущих версий не хочется, так что мне очень нужно знать его название. Буду благодарен, если кто-то его подскажет

Comment: Код ошибки: Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последней версии `react-router-dom` компонента `withRouter` больше нет - вместо него нужно использовать хуки `useParams`, `useLocation` и т.д. - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams